# Solving $6^{50-x} = 2^{50}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm being asked to solve an equation for $x$, giving the answer in the form below: $$a \log_{b} c$$

One of them is: $$6^{50-x} = 2^{50}$$

So I started by taking the $\log_6$ of both sides to give:
$$\log_{6}6^{50-x}=\log_{6}2^{50} \tag1$$

Leading to:
$$\begin{align}
50-x &=\log_{6}2^{50} \tag2 \\
50-x &=50\log_{6}2 \tag3 \\
-x &=-50+50\log_{6}2 \tag4
\end{align}$$
or finally:$$x=50-50\log_{6}2 \tag5$$

I've been given the answer of: $$x=50\log_{6}3 \tag6$$
How do I get from my answer to the correct form, or have I made a mistake along the way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

$$50 = \log_6 6^{50}$$

so you have

$$x = \log_6 6^{50} - 50\log_6 2=50 \log_6 6-50 \log_6 2$$

$$= 50 (\log_6 6 - \log_6 2) = 50 \log_6 3.$$

Comment: Brilliant! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Your last line:

$x= 50 -50\log_6 2$;

$x=50-50\log_6 ((2 \cdot 3)/ 3));$

Can you finish?

Option:

$(2 \cdot 3)^{50}=2^{50}6^x ;$

$2^{50}3^{50}=2^{50}6^x;$

$6^x=3^{50};$

$x=50 \log_6 3.$

Comment: The option is how I would go, seems to most natural.

Comment: zwim 7. Thanks for your comment:)